# Serving static files( including HTML files). Nginx vs Node.js. Which one is more scalable?

Tags: html, node.js, nginx, static-files

I'm curious if I could gain any advantage if I'll serve static HTML files using Node.js instead of Nginx. I know Nginx is written in C but does it serve files in a non-blocking fashion? I though Node.js can server more files(support more requests pe second) because I can write non-blocking code.

Answer (score 2):

Both Node.js and Nginx are asynchronous (non-blocking) servers.  Nginx is definitely more well suited for serving your static files.  However, depending on your use case, the difference may not be worth the added administration overhead.  You would really have to be running a significant amount of traffic before you would notice the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well I was thinking to use either node.js or Nginx to serve the cached html pages from one of my Rails apps( a social networking app with user pages that will remain unchanged for a lot of requests). What do you think about that?